# How to get the percentage of the "pull to refresh"?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml, android-library

I want to implement a functional *"pull to refresh"*. Also, it is required to do the following:

1. Customize panel appears with information about the update;
2. Show how much percent user pulled the panel before the update happens (something like a listener).

What library is used to implement the above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out this library which doesn't use `SwipeRefreshLayout` and instead implements a custom `View`.

Here: [CustomSwipeRefresh](https://github.com/xyxyLiu/SwipeRefreshLayout)

Or you can extend `SwipeRefreshLayout` and modify overscroll.

Now to answer your other question (which is different than your details). To calculate percentage, it really depends on what you are doing to get the data.

Are you:

1. Calling a network?
2. Loading some random data?
3. Getting it from a local DB?

Who knows?

Regardless you can then implement a custom `ProgressBar` inside your custom `SwipeRefreshLayout` or you can just put a `TextView` inside the `CustomSwipeRefresh` view from that other library.

Something like:

```
public void calculatePercentage() {
    // Do calculations to determine percentage
    setPercentage(...);
}

public void setPercentage(double per) {
    mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(per));
}
```

If it was up to me I would implement `Interface`s for this and use composition.

Something like:

```
public interface OnPercentageChangeListener {

    void beforePercentChanged();
    void percentChanged(double percent);
    void setPercentage(double percent);
    void afterPercentChanged();

}
```

Then just implement it in your custom views.